Wordpress Registration page load + Referral link issues
I want my wordpress website registration page to be able to open referral url like this -https://mywebsite.com/register/?ref=383892 when a user is registering using a referral link.
Anytime you put in the referral url, the page URL changes to https://mywebsite.com/register after loading
How do I make the registration page URL display the full URL with the referral details like this: https://mywebsite.com/register/?ref=383892
